# mysql query using joins -get data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT posts.content, posts.title, owners.firstname, 
owners.lastname, owners.email 
FROM posts,owners JOIN posts ON posts.owner_id = owners.owner_id;
```

I am trying to display (content, title, firstname, lastname, email) from both the tables (owners with the fields -owner_id,firstname,lastname,email and posts with the fields-id,owner_id,content,title,created_time,updated_time).

It shows,

> 'Not unique table/alias' error.

What's the solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query `FROM` part went wrong. You are kind a mixing old style and ANSI style `JOIN` syntax. It has to be like

```
FROM posts JOIN owners ON posts.owner_id = owners.owner_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT posts.content, posts.title, owners.firstname, owners.lastname, owners.email 
FROM owners 
JOIN posts ON posts.owner_id = owners.owner_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be wrong after FROM part, correct query is:

```
SELECT posts.content, posts.title, owners.firstname, owners.lastname, owners.email FROM posts JOIN owners ON posts.owner_id = owners.owner_id;
```

You can see more about JOIN in the [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)